# The multi-part identifier "IncomeExpenses.OperationId" could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the following fields:

```
OperationID,
Date,
TotalExpenses,
TotalIncome
```

I am using the SQL query below to get the difference between `TotalExpenses` and `TotalIncome` based on a specified `OperationID`:

```
select 
  (select (Date) from IncomeExpenses)
 ,(select (totalincome) from IncomeExpenses)
 -(select (totalexpenses) from IncomeExpenses) 
 where IncomeExpenses.OperationId  ='1'
```

However I am getting this error:

> The multi-part identifier "IncomeExpenses.OperationId" could not be bound

What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

For some reasons you're writing subqueries to select individual columns. There's no `FROM` clause in the outer query so you cannot write a `where` clause that references any table. Why are you not just writing

```
select date,
       totalincome-totalexpenses
from IncomeExpenses
where OperationId=1
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is SQL query it should look like that :

```
select Date, (totalincome - totalexpenses) as differencetotal
from IncomeExpenses  where OperationId  ='1'
```